# With AWS CDK Python, how to create a subdirectory, import a .py, and call a method in there?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, aws-cdk, setup.py, code-organization

I am attempting to get the simplest example of creating a S3 bucket with the AWS CDK Python with no luck.

I want to put the code to create the bucket in another file (which file exists in a subdirectory).

What I am doing works with every other Python project I have developed or started.

**Process:**

I created an empty directory:  `aws_cdk_python/`.  I then, inside that directory ran:
`$cdk init --language python` to layout the structure.

This created another subdirectory with the same name `aws_cdk_python/`, and created a single .py within that directory where I could begin adding code in the `__init__(self)` method (constructor)

I was able to add code there to create a S3 bucket.

Now I created a subdirectory, with an `__init__.py` and a file called:  `create_s3_bucket.py`

I put the code to create a S3 bucket in this file, in a method called 'main'

```
file: create_s3_bucket.py

def main(self): 
    <code to create s3 bucket here>
```

When I run the code, it will create the App Stack with no errors, but the S3 bucket will not be created.

---

**Here is my project layout:**

```
    aws_cdk_python/
        setup.py
        aws_cdk_python/
            aws_cdk_python_stack.py
            my_aws_s3/
                create_s3_bucket.py
```

**setup.py** contains the following two lines:

```
        package_dir={"": "aws_cdk_python"},
        packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="aws_cdk_python"),
```

The second line here says to look in the `aws_cdk_python/` directory, and search recursively in sub-folders for .py files

In aws_cdk_python_stack.py, I have this line:

`from my_aws_s3.create_s3_bucket import CreateS3Bucket`

then in `__init__ in` `aws_cdk_python_stack.py`, I instantiate the object:
`my_aws_s3 = CreateS3Bucket()`

**and then I make a call like so:**

`my_aws_s3.main()`  <== code to create the S3 bucket is here

I have followed this pattern on numerous Python projects before using `find_packages()` in `setup.py`

I have also run:
`$python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` which should pick up the dependencies pointed to in `setup.py`

**Questions:**
- Does anyone that uses the AWS CDK Python done this? or have recommendations for code organization?

I do not want all the code for the entire stack to be in `aws_cdk_python_stack.py`  `__init__()` method.

- Any ideas on why there no error displayed in my IDE? All dependencies are resolved, and methods found, but when I run, nothing happens?
- How can I see any error messages, no error messages appear with `$cdk deploy`, it just creates the stack, but not the S3 bucket, even though I have code to call and create a S3 bucket.

This is frustrating, it should work.

I have other sub-directories that I want to create under `aws_cdk_python/aws_cdk_python/<dir>` , put a `__init__.py` there (empty file) and import classes in the top level `aws_cdk_python_stack.py`

any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

---

**cdk.json** looks like this (laid down from `cdk init --language python`

```
{
  "app": "python app.py",
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:enableStackNameDuplicates": "true",
    "aws-cdk:enableDiffNoFail": "true",
    "@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports": "true",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecr-assets:dockerIgnoreSupport": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager:parseOwnedSecretName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-kms:defaultKeyPolicies": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-s3:grantWriteWithoutAcl": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs-patterns:removeDefaultDesiredCount": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-efs:defaultEncryptionAtRest": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeVersionProps": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021": true
  }
}
```

---

**app.py** looks like this

```
import os

from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import core
from aws_cdk_python.aws_cdk_python_stack import AwsCdkPythonStack


app = core.App()
AwsCdkPythonStack(app, "AwsCdkPythonStack",
    )

app.synth()
```

---

to date: **Tue 2021-12-31**, this has not been solved

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but I guess it depends on what your `cdk.json` file looks like. It contains the command to run for `cdk deploy`. E.g.:

```
{
  "app": "python main.py", <===== this guy over here assumes the whole app is instantiated by running main.py
  "context": {
   ...

  }
}
```

Since I don't see this entrypoint present in your project structure it might be related to that.

Usually after running `cdk init` you should at least be able to synthesize. usually in app.py you keep your main `App()` definition and stack and constructs go in subfolders. Stacks are often instantiated in `app.py` and the constructs are instantiated in the stack definition files.

I hope it helped you a bit further!

Edit:

Just an example of a working tree is shown below:

```
aws_cdk_python
├── README.md
├── app.py
├── cdk.json
├── aws_cdk_python
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── example_stack.py
│   └── s3_stacks                     <= this is your subfolder with s3 stacks
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── s3_stack_definition.py  <== file with an s3 stack in it
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── source.bat
```

aws_cdk_python/s3_stacks/s3_stack_definition.py:

```
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_s3


class S3Stack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        bucket = aws_s3.Bucket(self, "MyEncryptedBucket",
                        encryption=aws_s3.BucketEncryption.KMS
            )
```

app.py:

```
from aws_cdk import core

from aws_cdk_python.s3_stacks.s3_stack_definition import S3Stack


app = core.App()
S3Stack(app, "ExampleStack",
    )

app.synth()
```

Comment: cdk.json is created and has:  { "app": "python app.py":    - app.py defines the stack (in the latest cdk.  Everything there is in order and unmodified from what was laid down with app.py, I still cannot get this to work.  If there are any additional thoughts, please advise.

Comment: with my comment (and this still not working), if you can elaborate more, or provide a working example.  I updated the original post with my app.py and cdk.json, everything looks in order there.

Comment: Can you also post the definition of `AwsCdkPythonStack`? Since thats currently the only stack in app.py it also the only stack that will be synthesized. Im kindof confused at the project structure right now but if your goal is to create an s3 bucket you  can create a folder in the same directory as app.py and import any classes you define from app.py. Ill paste an example in my answer in a minute